# Can I modify the behaviour of backspace in gnu nano?

Tags: nano

I tried to configure my nano to more python friendly editor. I wrote  the following to my `.nanorc`

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
```

I was wondering if I can change the bahavior of backspace such that it removes four spaces at one press if there are only spaces on the left of the cursor and one space if there is at least one non-space character on the left on the cursor?

Comment: I can't be sure I'm not really into nano scripting configuration, but it's a very limited editor. And I'm almost sure it will not be possible to script to behaviour in Nano

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between v2.1 and 2.9 was the parameters added.

Check your version and check the below reference, just replace v2.9 with your version and check if tabsize and tabtospace is available.

https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.9/nanorc.5.html